# trigger change detection on a subcomponent

Tags: angular, jasmine

Suppose I am testing `MyComponent`  who's template contains `SubComponent`

MyComponent looks like this

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <sub-component [input]="property"></sub-component>
  `
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  property: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.property = 'value passed to sub component';
  }
}
```

When I test `MyComponent`, and do `comp.ngOnInit()`, `SubComponent` doesn't detect the updated value of `input`.

How can I have `SubComponent` detect that change ?

Comment: Does this even work at all? I see not `@Input` annotation, and even if there was, you are using wrong property name (`property`) in your child.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lifeCycle hook [OnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-interface.html) in your subComponent.